# How to connect an N64 to an Apple display (non) thunderbolt?

Tags: monitor, nintendo-64

I have an [Apple display (no thunderbolt)](http://www.apple.com/displays/) and an N64:

[image: N64].

I don't have a TV. Is there any way I can hook the Apple monitor up to the N64?

Comment: You'll probably just want to get a TV, but be careful; many TVs nowadays don't even have composite (yellow/white/red) video or S-video inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easily (or on the cheap). That display has only digital inputs, while the N64 only outputs analog video signals. Therefore you need a [converter box](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=video+to+hdmi+converter&hl=en&prmd=ivns&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1849&bih=1087&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=2808980670909790633&sa=X&ei=Hc1fTpzOOoGv8QP_rZXXAw&ved=0CLcBEPMCMAU#ps-sellers).

These come in many different shapes and sizes, generally the more expensive they are, the better the quality. They convert analog inputs (composite, or better S-Video) to HDMI or DVI output.

[image]

**But wait!** It's worse still. The particular display model you've linked has no more HDMI or DVI inputs, only Thunderbolt. Which means you need **another** converter box to translate the HDMI signal to Thunderbolt format, such as:

- [Kanex XD](http://www.kanexlive.com/xd)
- [Atlone AT-HD620](http://www.atlona.com/ATLONA-HDMI-MINI-DISPLAYPORT-TO-MINI-DISPLAYPORT-SCALER-AND-SWITCHER.html)

Altogether you're probably better off (and spend less money) with getting a TV or monitor with analogue inputs.

Comment: this cant be the best solution... I might as well get a TV then :\

Comment: Be aware that the only input the Thunderbolt Display has is its namesake: Thunderbolt.  It has no HDMI or DVI in.

Comment: You're right, +Nick T, I'll update the answer.

Comment: actually I have the older version... and it does not have thunderbolt

Answer (score 0):

I use a cinergy terratec USB 400 and eyetv setup. Us/jap modded N64 connects to terratec module via svideo and to my 2011 iMac by USB. Works well and relatively cheap. Thanks